# Mensagem de erro ao fechar o aplicativo

Tags: delphi, query, delphi-xe6

Tenho esse código que uso em uma tela de login, que quando o usuário usa a senha correta, ele direciona para a tela principal, até ai tudo ok, funciona perfeitamente, porem quando eu `fecho` o aplicativo ele apresenta uma mensagem do código.

> Nome ou senha do usuário inválidos. Se você esqueceu sua senha, consulte o administrador do sistema

```
procedure TFrmLogin.imgLoginClick(Sender: TObject);
var StrSqlLog, mensagem: String;
 begin
  sleep(500);
  strSqlLog:= 'select u.*, p.* '+
  'from usuario u inner join perfil p '+
  'on u.nivel = p.id '+
  'where u.nome = '+#39+
  edtName.Text+
  #39 + ' and u.senha = ' +
  #39 + edtPass.Text + #39;

  FrmHome.QueryLogin.Close;
  FrmHome.QueryLogin.SQL.Clear;
  FrmHome.QueryLogin.SQL.Add(strSqlLog);
  FrmHome.QueryLogin.Open();

   if FrmHome.QueryLogin.RecordCount = 1 then
  begin
    FreeAndNil(FrmLogin);
    Application.CreateForm(TFrmhome, Frmhome);
    Application.Run;
  end;

  if FrmHome.QueryLogin.RecordCount = 0 then
  begin
    mensagem:= 'Nome ou senha do usuário '+
    'inválidos.' + #13 + #13 +
    'Se você esqueceu sua '+
    'senha, consulte ' + #13 +
    'o administrador do sistema.';

    Application.MessageBox(PChar
    (mensagem),
    'Login não autorizado',
    MB_OK+MB_IconError);

    edtName.Clear;
    edtPass.Clear;
    edtName.SetFocus;
  end;
```

Comment: Pode ser que você tenha atribuído a mais algum evento a `procedure` `imgLoginClick`, já vi isso acontecendo ao duplicar botões na tela, verifica isso.

Comment: @David não tem nada no onclose do form,

Comment: Tudo indica que a procedure esta sendo chamada em algum outro momento. No evento OnExit de algum Edit, por exemplo.

Comment: Não faz sentido pois ele entra na condição que a query não tem nenhum registro.

Comment: Faz sim. Faz todo o sentido. O select é feito com base no  edtName.Text e edtPass.Text. Se o event onExit desse campo ou um outro evento qualquer chamar o método a query é montada sem usuário e sem senha e, claro,  não localizara nenhum registro que atenda essas condições.

Comment: Ok @ReginaldoRigo, mas eu garanto que não está sendo usado em nenhum lugar.

Comment: Se não forem muito extensos poste o PAS e o DFM dessa tela. Para postar o DFM com o form na tela pressione ALT+F12 e poste o código.

Comment: dfm é bem extenso.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40074/discussion-between-reginaldo-rigo-and-guilherme-lima).

Answer (score 3):

Fiz algumas modificações no evento onClick do componente imgLogin: 
(Considerando os forms Login e Home do lado Auto-create nas opções de projeto).

```
procedure TfrmLogin.LoginClick(Sender: TObject);
var StrSqlLog, mensagem: String;
 begin
  sleep(500);

  strSqlLog:= 'select u.*, p.* '+
  'from usuario u inner join perfil p '+
  'on u.nivel = p.id '+
  'where u.nome = '+#39+
  edtName.Text+
  #39 + ' and u.senha = ' +
  #39 + edtPass.Text + #39;

  FrmHome.QueryLogin.Close;
  FrmHome.QueryLogin.SQL.Clear;
  FrmHome.QueryLogin.SQL.Add(strSqlLog);
  FrmHome.QueryLogin.Open();

  if FrmHome.QueryLogin.RecordCount = 0 then
  begin
    mensagem:= 'Nome ou senha do usuário '+
    'inválidos.' + #13 + #13 +
    'Se você esqueceu sua '+
    'senha, consulte ' + #13 +
    'o administrador do sistema.';

    Application.MessageBox(PChar
    (mensagem),
    'Login não autorizado',
    MB_OK+MB_IconError);

    edtName.Clear;
    edtPass.Clear;
    edtName.SetFocus;
  end // fim do IF
  else
  begin
    // esconde a tela
    frmlogin.Hide;
    // chama a tela principal
    frmHome.ShowModal;
    // remove a tela Login da memória
    frmlogin.Release;
    // atribui conteúdo nulo para variável de tela frmLogin
    frmlogin := nil;
  end; // fim do Else

end; // fim da procedure LoginClick
```

Finalmente inclui código para o evento OnClose do form Home:

```
procedure TfrmHome.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
begin
  Application.Terminate;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

O problema é a forma que você está implementando. Note que o se o Rec for = 1, você vai criar a aplicação, isso vai interromper o processo.

Um teste simples a se fazer, é colocar um breakpoint no .Run, com isso você vai perceber que o restante desse código só vai ser acionado ao fechar a Application que você criou.

Não sei se serve para você, mas você poderia ter um Mainform, e a tela de login, e o restante do programa, fosse um Child do seu Mainform.

Outra situação, que não tem a ver com sua pergunta, mas eu acho que seria interessante você isolar essa regra de autenticação, pois esses tipos de regras, costumam ser usadas frequentemente.